# set title of java application opensuse

Tags: java, swing, jframe, opensuse

When running a Java Swing application in Opensuse, the name of the main class (`com-simontuffs-onejar-Boot`) appears at the top of the screen. How do I set that to be the title I want?

Version info:

```
/etc/SUSE-release
openSUSE 12.1 (i586)
VERSION = 12.1
CODENAME = Asparagus

uname -a 
Linux pax22 3.1.0-1.2-default #1 SMP Thu Nov 3 14:45:45 UTC 2011 (187dde0) i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

java -version
java version "1.6.0_12"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_12-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 11.2-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the `JFrame`?

Answer (score 11):

Did you try [`JFrame.setTitle(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)), e.g. `yourJFrame.setTitle("Title to display")`? I don't have an openSUSE box available at the moment to try it out myself…

**EDIT:** As it turns out (see comments, repeated it here for the sake of readability), it's a Gnome specific issue. This should resolve the issue:

```
Toolkit xToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
java.lang.reflect.Field awtAppClassNameField =
    xToolkit.getClass().getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
awtAppClassNameField.setAccessible(true);
awtAppClassNameField.set(xToolkit, applicationName);
```

See [this blog post](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2007/02/fixing-wmclass-for-your-java.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes. That sets the title on the frame but not at the top of the open suse screen.

Comment: @gerardw, in this case, I believe, it's an issue of the window manager/desktop environment in use. Which one are you running, KDE, Gnome, …? How do you start your application? Maybe there is some configuration file you need to create (some time ago at least KDE used `.desktop` files for some things, IIRC)… I think a screenshot would be helpful too (for people like me who have no openSUSE available)… ;-)

Comment: That's the ticket! Turns out it's a gnome thing, and I found the solution on this blog http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2007/02/fixing-wmclass-for-your-java.html

`Toolkit xToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  java.lang.reflect.Field awtAppClassNameField =
      xToolkit.getClass().getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
  awtAppClassNameField.setAccessible(true);
  awtAppClassNameField.set(xToolkit, applicationName);`

Comment: it was great and fun until Java 9, now this code issues bunch of warnings with threats that in the future all this is going to be denied.

Comment: @mariusm, if you need this functionality I suggest you to leave a comment at [JDK-6528430](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6528430) that the presented workaround has an "expiration date" and thus the priority should be increased. I'm not sure how to sign up to the bug system though. Maybe information on [How to contribute](http://openjdk.java.net/contribute/) or posting to an appropriate [mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo) can help…

Comment: thanks @siegi, but that's just one bug, I've seen many more, I could make some more noise, but I don't have an account there... The issue is not some appClassName, but the app name display in the taskbar etc -- this need to have proper support in JDK. Also MacOS seem to have their own solution (which is not so invasive, yet completely different). It's just crazy stupid design, I start believing that lawyers took over the development when Oracle took over.

Comment: it would be so much better if they just used the window title as the appname, but no, they had to dig some obscure class name.

Answer (score 3):

If the `setTitle(String)` does not work for you, look to deploy using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It can set an app. title on most platforms, and do much more besides.